# Quiero agregar una columna con la fecha en un nuevo data.frame formado con variables transformadas de valores minuto a valores dia

Tags: r, aggregate

Tengo un archivo con variables climáticas que fueron registradas por una estación meteorológica cada 15 minutos. Estoy armando un nuevo data frame con los valores transformados a valores día (suma o promedio, según la variable). En este nuevo data frame, quiero agregar la columna fecha. He probado de muchas maneras y no he tenido éxito.
Es la primera vez que hago una consulta, si no es la forma correcta, agradezco que me orienten.
Muchas gracias! P.D: Quise enviar el archivo excel pero no se como agregarlo.

Este es el error:

```
climazh.agsm<-aggregate(climazh.agsm$fecha,list(dia=climazh$dia),FUN=length)[,1]
```

Este es ejemplo minimo reproducible

```
ejemplo<-structure(list(dia=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), fecha=c(12/06/2020, 12/06/2020, 12/06/2020, 13/06/2020, 13/06/2020, 13/06/2020),
                        RH=c(96.7,  97.1,   97.3, 90,   88.8,   88.3),temperature=c(17, 17.1,   17.1,15.8   ,15.8,  15.7),rainfall=c(0,2,0,3,0,7),
                        
class="data.frame"))

               

climazh.agsm<-data.frame(dia=aggregate(climazh$dia,list(dia=climazh$dia),FUN=length)[,1],
                         rainfall.sum=aggregate(climazh$rainfall,list(dia=climazh$dia),FUN=sum)[,2],
                         temperature.mean=round(aggregate(climazh$temperature,list(climazh$dia),FUN=mean)[,2],2),
                         RH.mean=round(aggregate(climazh$RH,list(climazh$dia),FUN=mean)[,2],2),
                         RH.per=aggregate(climazh$RH.filtro,list(dia=climazh$dia),FUN=sum)[,2],
                         rain.per=aggregate(climazh$rainfall.filtro,list(dia=climazh$dia),FUN=sum)[,2])
```

Comment: Hola Elena! Seria adecuado que incluyas una parte de tus datos. Puedes usar la función `dput()`sobre una parte de ellos `dput(head(datos))` y después copias y pegas el resultado en tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias. Modifique los datos y creo que ahora quedaron bien para que puedan reproducir el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que estás usando `aggregate` de forma excesiva y poco práctica. Basemonos en el sgte `data.frame` de ejemplo (creando fechas cada 15 minutos):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

periodo <- seq(ymd_hm('2022-01-01 00:00'),ymd_hm('2022-03-31 23:45'), by = '15 mins')

longi_ejemplo <- length(periodo)

df <- data.frame(fecha = periodo,
                 rainfall = sample(c(rep(0,longi_ejemplo/2),
                                     abs(rnorm(longi_ejemplo/2, mean = 5))),
                                   size = longi_ejemplo),
                 temperature = rnorm(longi_ejemplo, mean = 15, sd = 5),
                 RH = sample(x = 0:100,size = longi_ejemplo,replace = T))
```

Usando las funciones de `dplyr` puedes crear una nueva fecha por día, agrupar las filas por esa nueva fecha y calcular el estadístico adecuado por variable (por ejemplo, la lluvia sería la suma de las observaciones del día mientras que para la temperatura, puede ser media, mínimo y/o máximo):

```
df %>% mutate(fecha_dia = as.Date(fecha)) %>% 
  select(-fecha) %>% 
  group_by(fecha_dia) %>% 
  summarise(rainfall = sum(rainfall),
            temperature = mean(temperature),
            RH = mean(RH)) %>% 
  ungroup() -> df_dia
```

El resultado es como el sgte:

```
df_dia
# # A tibble: 90 × 4
#    fecha_dia  rainfall temperature    RH
#    <date>        <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  2022-01-01     277.        14.4  52.4
# 2  2022-01-02     254.        14.7  49.2
# 3  2022-01-03     254.        13.8  48.0
# 4  2022-01-04     185.        15.2  51.8
# 5  2022-01-05     268.        14.8  46.6
# 6  2022-01-06     200.        14.5  46.8
# 7  2022-01-07     290.        15.4  48.1
# 8  2022-01-08     214.        14.1  52.0
# 9  2022-01-09     201.        15.1  45.9
# 10 2022-01-10     239.        14.7  50.4
# # … with 80 more rows
```